# How to add soap header when making a soap request using the java objects generated by wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soap-client, soapheader

I generated client java objects using JAX-WS RI. I am trying to make a SOAP request to a web service. Service requires authentication in the header which looks like below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
<xsd:authHeader>
<xsd:user>username@gmail.com</xsd:user>
<xsd:password>password1</xsd:password>
</xsd:authHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ns:searchAssetsParam>
<ns:includeSubfolders>true</ns:includeSubfolders>
<ns:resultsPage>2</ns:resultsPage>
</ns:searchAssetsParam>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The generated java objects have methods for calling the service, creating the objects and constructing the header. But, I am having trouble setting the header while making the call.

Here's the code that I am using:

```
IpsApiService service = new IpsApiService();
IpsApiPortType port = service.getIpsApiSoapPort();
SearchAssetsParam searchAssetsParam = buildSearchAssetsParam();
SearchAssetsReturn response = port.searchAssets(searchAssetsParam);
```

buildSearchAssetsParam() constructs the request object. 
I created the header object as follows:

```
AuthHeader header = new AuthHeader();
header.setUser("username@gmail.com");
header.setPassword("password1");
```

How do I set this AuthHeader to the service request?

Thanks,
Venu

Answer (score 18):

Once I had the same problem. I needed to modify the `JAX-WS` web service SOAP header at every request. To solve this problem I have created a handler like this:

```
public class MyHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandler.class);

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
            SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            if (header == null) {
                header = envelope.addHeader();
            }
            QName qNameUserCredentials = new QName("https://your.target.namespace/", "UserCredentials");
            SOAPHeaderElement userCredentials = header.addHeaderElement(qNameUserCredentials);

            QName qNameUsername = new QName("https://your.target.namespace/", "Username");
            SOAPHeaderElement username = header.addHeaderElement(qNameUsername );
            username.addTextNode(this.username);
            QName qNamePassword = new QName("https://your.target.namespace/", "Password");
            SOAPHeaderElement password = header.addHeaderElement(qNamePassword);
            password.addTextNode(this.password);

            userCredentials.addChildElement(username);
            userCredentials.addChildElement(password);

            message.saveChanges();
            //TODO: remove this writer when the testing is finished
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            message.writeTo(new StringOutputStream(writer));
            LOGGER.debug("SOAP message: \n" + writer.toString());
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while adding credentials to SOAP header.", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error occurred while writing message to output stream.", e);
        }
        return true;
    }

    //TODO: remove this class after testing is finished
    private static class StringOutputStream extends OutputStream {

        private StringWriter writer;

        public StringOutputStream(StringWriter writer) {
            this.writer = writer;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            writer.write(b);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        LOGGER.debug("handleFault has been invoked.");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
        LOGGER.debug("close has been invoked.");
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        LOGGER.debug("getHeaders has been invoked.");
        return null;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

It adds the needed parameters to my `SOAP` header and it is invoked on every request. All you need to do is to modify `handleMessage` method to suit your needs.

Comment: i am Created stub by using Axis2, so how i can add this, i am also facing same problem

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer, saved my precious days :)

Answer (score 2):

It works for me by overriding the `public void setAttribute(String namespace, String localName, String value)` method.

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.axis.Constants;
import org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHeaderElement;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ADESHeaderElement  extends SOAPHeaderElement 
{

     public ADESHeaderElement(QName qname, Object value)
        {
            super(qname, value);
        }

     @Override
     public void setAttribute(String namespace, String localName, String value) 
     {
       if (!Constants.ATTR_MUST_UNDERSTAND.equals(localName)) 
       {  // Or any other attribute name you'd want to avoid
         super.setAttribute(namespace, localName, value);
       }
     }
}
```

Create header element like this:

```
 ADESHeaderElement custheader = new ADESHeaderElement(qname, clientserv);          
        custheader.setActor(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create your service from classess generated by cxf, add custom interceptor

```
Service service = new MyService(wsdlURL, new QName("http://myservice.com/MyService/", "MyService"));
MyPort port = service.getMyPort();
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
// adding interceptor programmatically
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new MyHeaderHandler());
```

Your can extend AbstractSoapInterceptor to implement your custom interceptor to handle message.

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.headers.Header;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;

import com.rpc.core.utils.DomainContext;

public class MyHeaderHandler extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    /**
    * Constructor
    */
    public MyHeaderHandler() {
        super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);

    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage message) throws org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault {
        try {
            message.getHeaders().add(new Header(new QName("MyCustomHeader"),"value", new JAXBDataBinding(String.class)));
             } catch (JAXBException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         };
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did the same that Rangappa Tungal, following this example:

```
Service w = new ServiceLocator();  
ServiceSoap ws = new ServiceSoapStub(new URL(w.getServiceSoapAddress()),w); Stub mystub = (Stub) ws;
AuthHeader up = new AuthHeader("user","pass");
mystub.setHeader("namespace", "AuthHeader", up);
ws.get***();
```

[Link to the example!](http://forums.devshed.com/java-help-9/java-axis-soap-auth-header-213041.html)