# Add Header To all outgoing CXF request

Tags: spring, client, cxf

Is it possible to add a Header to all outgoing cxf connections, from the client side.

Using Spring 3.0 and CXF 2.6.0

Comment: Connections? Did you mean requests? Then yeah, it's possible.

Comment: yeah requests, if so how :)?

Comment: CXF Interceptors are another option. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16743238/1030409

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how i did,

Spring.xml

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />

<bean id="cxf" class="org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBus">
    <property name="outInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="headerInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="inInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="headerInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="headerInterceptor" class="logging.Interceptor"/>
```

Interceptor:

```
 public class UUIDHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor {


private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UUIDHeaderInterceptor.class);



public UUIDHeaderInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);

}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {

        Map<String, List<String>> headers = (Map<String, List<String>>) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS);
        headers.put(REQUEST_ID_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, Arrays.asList(new String[]{"TEST"}));

   }
 }

@Override
public void handleFault(Message message) {
    handleMessage(message);
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

I would like to give my two cents here . I am solving the same case here in my post -

http://saurzcode.in/2014/05/08/adding-header-to-soap-request-using-cxf-2/

Spring Configuration :-

```
<jaxws:client id="mywebServiceClient"
    serviceClass="com.saurzcode.TestService"
    address="http://saurzcode.com:8088/mockTestService">

    <jaxws:binding>
        <soap:soapBinding version="1.2" mtomEnabled="true" />
    </jaxws:binding>
</jaxws:client>
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="com.saurzcode.ws.caller.SoapHeaderInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

CXF Interceptor -

```
public class SoapHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public SoapHeaderInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.POST_LOGICAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        List<Header> headers = message.getHeaders();
        TestHeader testHeader = new TestHeader();
        JAXBElement<TestHeader> testHeaders = new ObjectFactory()
        .createTestHeader(testHeader);

        try {
            Header header = new Header(testHeaders.getName(), testHeader,
            new JAXBDataBinding(TestHeader.class));
            headers.add(header);
            message.put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: It works fine except that my inner elements are without namespace prefix - like this:
     <soap:Header>
      <ns2:TestHeader xmlns:ns2="namespace_uri">
         <InnerElement>
         </InnerElement>
      </ns2:TestHeader>
    </soap:Header>
Could anybody please help?

Comment: how to add interceptor without spring? just using cxf wsdl2java client

Answer (score 4):

I already know two ways of doing this. One is to create your SOAP Handler and register it as `JAX-WS` handler in your Spring config.

Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956562/how-to-add-soap-header-when-making-a-soap-request-using-the-java-objects-generat/12712728#12712728) how to create a SOAP handler. As you want header to appear in the response (outgoing request) don't forget that you then need to check if the message is outbound, something like this would do:

```
Boolean outbound = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
if (outbound) {
    //Modify your header.
}
```

The other, maybe more easier way. Put the header directly into CXF response context. Please note that this example is only proof of concepts, I don't know the situation in reality where you need credentials in the response. It will display how to add user credentials object into the header, you have to modify it depending on your needs.

```
private void modifyResponse(String username, String password) {
    UserCredentials authHeader = new UserCredentials();
    authHeader.setUsername(username);
    authHeader.setPassword(password);
    ArrayList<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>(1);
    try {
        Header soapHeader = new Header(
                new QName("http://yournamespaceuri.com/something", "UserCredentials"),
                authHeader,
                new JAXBDataBinding(UserCredentials.class));
        headers.add(soapHeader);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Exception trying to serialize header: {}", ex);
    }
    ((BindingProvider) proxy).getResponseContext().put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);
}
```

This method needs to be called just after the request your client.

Comment: sorry, I realise this message was posted a long time ago, but what is the proxy object here? Where did it come from? Thanks

Comment: @AliH That's a valid question. I think proxy is injected WebServiceContext e.g. `@Resource
    private WebServiceContext proxy;` 

Refer to this https://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-HowcanIaddsoapheaderstotherequest/response?

Comment: `proxy` is an instance of web service's port type which comes from the [Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Service.html) class. For e.g.: 

`Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
YourWebService proxy = service.getPort(YourWebService.class);`

Where url is you published endpoint URL and qname is a namespace mapping with generated service class.