# How to Add/Read Custom Header from each SOAP Response/Request throw Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, header

I have to add a custom Header into my SOAP Response and Read Header from SOAP Request
what I did so far referring to this links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956562/how-to-add-soap-header-when-making-a-soap-request-using-the-java-objects-generat) and [link2](http://blog.jdevelop.eu/?p=67) as follows

**Web Service Class:**

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService()
@HandlerChain(name = "SoapHandler", file = "soaphandler.xml")
public class FooService {

    @WebMethod()
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + name);
        return "Hello " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

**SOAP Handler Class:**

```
package com.webservice;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class SoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SoapHandler.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext arg0) {
        System.out.println("Colse Method");
        LOGGER.info("Close Method");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext arg0) {
        System.out.println("handleFault Method");
        LOGGER.info("handleFault Method");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext arg0) {
        System.out.println("handleMessage Method");
        LOGGER.info("handleMessage Method");
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        System.out.println("getHeaders Method");
        LOGGER.info("getHeaders Method");
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Tester Class**

```
public class Tester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FooServiceServiceLocator locator = new FooServiceServiceLocator();
            FooService fooService = locator.getFooServicePort();
            System.out.println(fooService.sayHello("ashish"));
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Handler Chain Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jws:handler-chains xmlns:jws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
  <jws:handler-chain>
    <jws:handler>
      <jws:handler-name>SoapHandler</jws:handler-name>
      <jws:handler-class>com.webservice.SoapHandler</jws:handler-class>
    </jws:handler>
  </jws:handler-chain>
</jws:handler-chains>
```

when I am calling this Tester class it gives me correct output as "Hello ashish!" 
and my 
`handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext arg0)` 
method is getting executed when request comes in and goes out so how can I *differentiate between Incoming Request and outgoing Response* in my

```
handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext arg0) method ? so that when request comes in I can read Header and when response goes out then I can Add my header into it Thanks....
```

Comment: have you configured the handler chain?

Comment: @balaji krishnan yes I have configured the handler chain as given in Link2 and my SOAP Handler is working but  handleMessage() method is executing twice when request comes in and goes out, now problem is how can I differentiate between the incoming request and outgoing response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the context argument that you get in handleMessage

```
arg0.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
```

and check the retunred boolean to identify the msg as request/response

Comment: I am using same code as you mentioned as                             Object bOutbound = messageContext.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY); it means when it return Boolean.TRUE value then it is Response and when Boolean.FALSE then it is Request is it so ?

Comment: yes, you are right. javadoc here:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html#MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY

Comment: hey thanks it works for me but one more thing How can I exclude some methods from Handler Chain configuration ? i.e suppose I have one more method in FooService class as sayHey() and I want to exclude this method from this SoapHandler class ?

Comment: i dont think you can do that.. those are the methods defined in the SOAPHandler & SOAPMessageContext interfaces..Not suggested way but, may be you can create another class overriding all the methods and in your needed class just extend it and override getMessage. As alwasys with interfaces, you need to provide the implementation in some way or the other

Comment: you can have handlers implemented both at the server and client end.
if you are inclunding some content in all the request headers, do it in the client side handler and extract the header content & validate it in the server end handler.. just like the Filters we use in web apps